# How to update a field in one table based off values in another table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I'm trying to update a a field in one table based off calculations from fields in a second table and I can't seem to get any syntax to work.

For example,

```
Update item1 i1, item2 i2
Set i1.min_qty = i2.cases * i2.qty_per_case
Where i1.item_id = i2.item_id
And i1.flag1 = 'Y'
```

The relationship between `i1.item_id` and `i2.item_id` is one to one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a correlated subquery or merge statement:

```
update item1 i1
set    i1.min_qty = (select i2.cases * i2.qty_per_case
                     from   item2 i2
                     where  i1.item_id = i2.item_id)
where  i1.flag1 = 'Y';

merge into item1 tgt
using item2 src
  on (tgt.item_id = src.item_id)
when matched then
update set tgt.min_qty = src.cases * src.qty_per_case
where  tgt.flag1 = 'Y';
```

N.B. untested.

Comment: Similar question today itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625110/sql-update-in-a-select-rank-over-partition-sentence